# StackView: storing components along with their items

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Consider the following code:

```
StackView {
    id: stack
}

Component {
    id: componentFooBar
    FooBar {}
}
...
stack.push({item: componentFooBar})
```

In the example above, according to the Qt source and documentation, after `componentFooBar` is pushed to the stack its inner item (`FooBar`) is loaded and pushed to the top of the inner stack. And if I want to access stack head (either by `pop()` or `get(0)`), I'll get `FooBar` instance, not its `Component`. So for Qml `StackView` there's no invariant like

```
stack.push(X)
X === stack.pop()
```

Is there any way to access pushed `Component`s? The only idea I have for now is to write some wrappers for `push()`/`pop()`/`get()` methods and store `Component`s in some separate stack:

```
StackView {
    property var componentStack: []
    function _push (x) {
        push(x)
        componentStack.push(x)
    }
    function _pop (x) {
        pop(x)
        return componentStack.pop()
    }
}
```

But for me it looks like an hack, also I have a lot of code using default `push()`/`pop()` methods. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Why do you need access to the component?

Comment: @Mitch More generally, I need an invariant "what is pushed could be poped back, what is poped could be pushed again". Even more generally - I need some way to save/backup StackView, do something with it (clear, pop, push), and then restore it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an array of your components, such as here:

   ```
   StackView {
      id: stackView
   }

   property variant myObjects: [component1.createObject(), component2.createObject(), component3.createObject()] 

   Component {
      id: component1
   }

   Component {
      id: component2
   }

   Component {
      id: component3
   }
   ```
2. Then when pushing to `StackView` make sure to use `destroyOnPop` property:

   ```
   stackView.push({item: myObjects[componentIndex], destroyOnPop: false})
   ```

By following these two steps, `StackView` does not take ownership by your objects. Therefore, you can work with objects directly and still push/pop many times to `StackView`.

Comment: The `destroyOnPop` is not needed since `StackView` only destroys by default items pushed as components or URLs, here it pushed as an `Item` directly.
The push statement could then be rewritten like : `stackView.push(myObjects[componentIndex])`