# QtQuick.Controls 2 StackView and destroyOnPop

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have application which uses StackView and pushes a lot of dynamic created objects into this StackView and I need some way to destroy this objecst when they are popped from StackView. If I use Controls 1 Stackview, I can just push object with destroyOnPop property (like it was shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626053/stackview-storing-components-along-with-their-items)):

```
tablesStack.push({item: view, destroyOnPop: true})
```

but it doesn't applicable to Controls 2 StackView. What is correct solution of this problem?

I know only one way: call object.destroy() with delay when I pop it, but this way looks like kludge. If it is important, I can add any code to dynamic generated objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controls 2 `StackView` has simplified ownership semantics. `StackView` takes ownership of any item that it has dynamically instantiated. If you have created the instance, then you're in control of the instance. In other words, if you want `StackView` to destroy, push `Component`s or URLs and let `StackView` create the instances.

If you need access the created instance, you can simply handle the return value:

```
var view = stackView.push(component, {"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
view.doSomething()
```

Comment: It works with Qt.createComponent from file, thanks, but I haven't understand how I should change my code when I use Qt.createQmlObject ? My test code is here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/372c58e7f53531bd6e51950d611e33a7

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the main reason for using `Qt.createQmlObject()`? It is a nice trick for avoiding hard dependencies etc. but in most cases more explicit components are seemingly better. Anyway, with QtQuick Controls 2.1 in Qt 5.8 you can do: `Rectangle { StackView.onDeactivated: destroy() }`. With 2.0 you you'll presumably have to resort to checking the status: `Rectangle { StackView.onStatusChanged: if (StackView.status === StackView.Inactive) destroy() }`

Comment: It works, thanks. Reason to use  createQmlObject is very simple: I dynamic create views for tables from few sqlite bases and I don't know what fields will contain tables in runtime. Historicaly I often changed tables struct in the beginning and it was just way to not forget change some qml. If you are interested in my code, here is my github https://github.com/aknew/CoinsVariationBase

Comment: I have been wrong, StackView.onStatusChanged: is not correct because it triggers on both pop this item or push new, so if I push item whis this code, push another item after it and tried to pop - I cannot go back

Comment: I have created [QTBUG-55405](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55405) to make sure that this oversight gets fixed in the future releases. But for now, we need a temporary workaround for you, right? I don't have access to a development environment right now so I cannot play with it, but checking `StackView.index` to see whether the item is on the stack could be one possibility. It gets ugly and clumsy, but basically something like `StackView.onIndexChanged: { if (StackView.index === -1 && StackView.status === StackView.Inactive) destroy() }` hopefully does the trick.

Comment: The last solution really works, but you are right - it is strange, so I will wait Controls 2.1. But thanks anyway for you answers and time.